# Xamarin custom MarkupExtension not working with Type property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom MarkupExtension in Xamarin forms using `Type` as property. Unfortunately I am not able to pass a property of `Type`, in my case the property is always `null`. Here is the minimal example of my MarkupExtension, returing the full name of a type as string:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(TheType))]
public class TypeMarkupExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public Type TheType { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        return TheType?.FullName ?? "Failure";
    }
}
```

But what ever I tried, using the MarkupExtension is not possible because `TheType` is always `null` and my return value is `"Failure"`. Here is the way I tried to use the extension like:

```
<Label Text="{local:TypeMarkup x:Int16}"/>
<Label Text="{local:TypeMarkup {x:Type x:Int16}}"/>
```

The code runs perfectly if I use a simple `string` as property type. For me it looks like passing `Type` as property is not possible. Is this correct or is there a problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option-1: Specify property-name

You need to use a nested markup-extension here (which you already did); but you also need to specify the name of property. Otherwise, my tests show, it is treated as a string value and assigned to default content property - hence, a type mismatch.

So, specifying property name explicitly as following should resolve the issue:

```
<Label Text="{local:TypeMarkup TheType={x:Type x:Int16}}" ../>
```

---

#### Option-2: Use Xaml type resolver

You can use `XamlTypeResolver` (ref: [TypeExtension in Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/TypeExtension.cs))

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(TheType))]
public class TypeMarkupExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string TheType { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TheType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TheType isn't set.");
        
        if (serviceProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));

        var typeResolver = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver)) as IXamlTypeResolver;
        if (typeResolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("No IXamlTypeResolver in IServiceProvider");

        var resolvedType = typeResolver.Resolve(TheType, serviceProvider);
        return resolvedType?.FullName ?? "Failure";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, this exactly solves my problem, many thanks. A small supplement to your second solution: Using the already existing implementation like `TypeExtension te = new TypeExtension()
{
    TypeName = TheType
};` and getting the type with `Te.ProvideValue(ServiceProvider);` is a very smart solution in my view.